# Best way to seed content text in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

I know how to create a standard seed file in rails and seed my database.  However, I have a wysiwyg editor that I used to create many pages of content.  The content field is a "text" type and contains a full page of HTML.  I will be exporting this data out and want to create a seed file with it.

Any ideas on the best way to create my seed files?

For example, should I create a reference the content from separate files? or should I just keep the text in one seed file? Would it be possible to show an example of a recommendation?

Comment: Do you need to store some meta data, or do you create a model with a single text attribute?

Comment: I have other attributes in addition to the text attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option if you have multiple attributes and the data is already in the DB, you can use seed_dump gem: https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump

so given an existing DB, running

```
rake db:seed:dump
```

will produce the following in the `seed.rb`:

```
Product.create!([
  { category_id: 1, description: "Long Sleeve Shirt", name: "Long Sleeve Shirt" },
  { category_id: 3, description: "Plain White Tee Shirt", name: "Plain T-Shirt" }
])
User.create!([
  { password: "123456", username: "test_1" },
  { password: "234567", username: "test_2" }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a file containing the content and then just reading it and seeding your db:

```
file_content = File.read('path to file with extension');
MyModel.create(text: file_content);
```

And of course, if you have multiple items you need to seed, just loop over them with the right file name or by all file in certain directory.

Comment: If I have other attribute, do I put them in the file as a hash or something?